# dir() function in commandline vs IDLE

Tags: python

I've tried running the following code in IDLE:

```
import sys
dir(sys)
```

There is no result:

```
>>>
```

But when I run it in the command line, i get this:

```
>>> dir(sys)
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_getframe', '_mercurial', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info', 'exc_traceback', 'exc_type', 'exc_value', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'gettrace', 'getwindowsversion', 'hexversion', 'long_info', 'maxint', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'py3kwarning', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions', 'winver']
```

Can someone explain the difference in what I did?

Comment: command line behaves as having an implicit print on it. Is like when you write 3 + 5, you are like doing print(3+5)

Comment: The interactive shell always echoes the value returned by the last operation, but a python script doesn't do that (it is not *interactive* in the way the shell environment is). This is why you have to use the `print` statement (python 2.x) or function (python 3.x) in a script, as outlined by @RobWouters in his answer.

Comment: @joaquin - Nope, it does not have any implicit `print`. Try for yourself noticing the diffeerence between issuing `u'Bar'` and `print u'Bar'` in the shell...

Comment: if your running interactively in idle you shouldn't have to explicitly call a print command. What happens when you try to get the value of some other variables? Maybe you have the builtin dir overwritten  with somethin else?

Comment: @mac Oh you're right thanks, In command line `u'Bar'` is the same as `print repr(u'Bar')`. is that like this as a general rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem is a misunderstanding of what `dir()` does. If you use it at the interactive Python prompt `>>>`, it is easy to think it means "print the names available in the given object." However, what it actually does is *return* the names available in the given object.

As a convenience, the interactive Python shell prints the result of the last statement, if any (`None` is assumed to mean that the statement did not produce a result). So when you do `dir()` at the `>>>` prompt, the result of `dir()` is printed. However, it is not `dir()` but the Python shell that does the printing.

So in your IDLE session, you are executing `dir()` but not doing anything with the result. Since you are not executing the statement interactively but as a script, Python doesn't automatically print it for you, since it doesn't know you want that (indeed, most of the time you don't). You could store it in a variable for later use:

```
sysdir = dir(sys)
```

Since it's a list, you could iterate over it:

```
for n in dir(sys):
    # do something
```

Or you could print it:

```
print dir(sys)    # Python 3 requires print(dir(sys))
```

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly call for a `print` of the representation of your object on the standard output :

```
# Python 3.x.
print(dir(sys))

# Python 2.x
print dir(sys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try to [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) which is quite convenient to avoid confusion regarding returned values (`Out` is displayed) and printed values (`Out` is not displayed):

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: dir(sys)
Out[2]:
['__displayhook__',
 ...
 'warnoptions']

In [3]: print(dir(sys))
['__displayhook__', ... , 'warnoptions']
```

Note: I've added the `...` to make the output shorter.

Comment: @jcollado--how do i install ipython from the egg?

Comment: @codeninja It should be possible to install the egg with `pip` or `easy_install`.

Comment: @jcollado--im pretty new to python... any chance you could guide me through this? I downloaded ez_setup and added it to the `setup.py` file, but there are still errors coming up.

Comment: @codeninja That depends on the OS you're using. In linux it should be pretty easy to install just the package that you need. On other OSes, the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/install/index.html) should provide enough information.